# South American Rocks

Tags: petrology

I'm thinking of visiting South America at some stage, to look at some interesting geology in the Atacama, Patagonian Andes, etc. Does anyone know where the best geological museum is in South America? I have a particular fancy to see what unusual lithologies South America has to offer.